# Android AT commands how they work and why most of them give errors

Tags: android, at-command

Hi i am working on an android app, and need in depth gsm details.  So there seems to be massive amounts of at commands to give you this, for instance AT+CCED=? , you can find one of it references [here](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/CellularShield/SM5100B%20AT%20Command%20Set.pdf)

my problem is , a massive amount of these codes just comes back with error.  Is it because its device specific?  and if so where do i get the spec for a specific device.
An example command i am running would be as follows

```
echo -c "AT+CCED=?\r\n" > /dev/smd11
```

Comment: Can you give example to a coomand **and** the error you're getting?

Comment: ah this here is the problem, it just says error. even with error messages set to 1 with the CCED command. Some commands work, just not any useful ones

Comment: this is highly device(as in combination of both hardware and software) specific